# Skip current directory, but allow all sub directories in grep

Tags: linux, grep

How do I skip grep searching files in the current directory, but search files in all the sub directories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a wildcard that matches all the subdirectories as the argument.

```
grep -R pattern */
```

The `/` at the end forces it to only match directories (including symbolic links to directories).

Answer (score 1):

I guess the following could do:

```
grep -R pattern $(find -type d -maxdepth 1)
```

Here we use `$(find -type d -maxdepth 1)` to get the list of subdirectories in the current directory.

**Update:** one difference to the nice Barmar's solution is that `find` would also fetch hidden subdirectories with names starting with a dot.